# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when using enumerate?

Tags: python, enumerate

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game, the problem is the function that checks the table and then updates it with the players '0' or 'X' at the chosen index.

Please tell me how I can fix this because I can't see what's wrong with this.

```
table = [['1','2','3'],
         ['4','5','6'],
         ['7','8','9']]

def title():
    for row in table:
        print row

def check(indx, sym):
    for indd, row in enumerate(table):
        for ind, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == indx and cell != '0' or cell != 'X':
                table[indd][ind] = sym
            else:
                return False

def main():

    moves_left = 1
    while moves_left > 0:
        if moves_left == 1:
            title()
            indx = raw_input('Where do you want your nought?: ')
            new_table = check(indx, '0')
            if new_table != False:
                moves_left += 1
            else:
                print 'Invalid selection'
        elif moves_left == 2:
            title()
            indx = raw_input('Where do you want your cross?: ')
            new_table = check(indx, 'X')
            if new_table != False:
                moves_left -= 1
            else:
                print 'Invalid Selection'
        else:
            print 'it\'s a draw'

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

My Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tictac.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "tictac.py", line 28, in main
    new_table = check(indx, '0')
  File "tictac.py", line 19, in check
    table[indd[ind]] = sym
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeveloperXY already got your immediate problem.  There are several more.  The one vexing you at the moment is because your **if** logic is incorrect:

```
if cell == indx and cell != '0' or cell != 'X':
```

Either use parentheses, or learn the order of evaluation for Boolean operators.  Among other things, this statement must *always* come up True at the start: every cell is something other than 'X'.  Since you perform the update for *every* cell in the loop, you change them *all* to '0'.

Instead, you need to design logic that finds the one cell you want to change (at cell == indx) and then changes only that *one* cell.  Try this for starters:

```
def check(indx, sym):
    for indd, row in enumerate(table):
        for ind, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == indx:
                table[indd][ind] = sym
print table  # I added this to watch what happens to the actual game state.
```

Note that I got rid of the return value: you were returning either **None** or **False**, which have the same effect in the statement **if new_table**.
By the way, notice that if you return **True** from **check**, then **moves_left** becomes 2, and your main program goes into an infinite loop.

Now, note that your **title** function pays no attention at all to the game state: it won't print anything but the initial numbering.

Does that move you along far enough to close this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
table[indd[ind]] = sym # you're treating an integer like a list, which is wrong
```

to

```
table[indd][ind] = sym
```

in order to access the cell at the '`indd`'th row & '`ind`'th column.

Actually, `table[indd[ind]]` is a short hand for doing this:

```
table.__getitem__(indd.__getitem__(ind))
```

& integers don't have a [**getitem**()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) special method.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, while I don't get a traceback now, this just sets all the cells of the table to 0.

Comment: `check(indx, '0')` you're always passing **0** to the method in charge of setting the cells.

Comment: yes because it's noughts and crosses. that should only change the cell equal to indx if it isn't already a 0 or x. It shouldn't change all cells to 0.

Comment: Could you update your post with the minimal, "relevant" code in order to run ?